# In Prestashop I am getting a combinational error because of the default combination only being added to the cart

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I have 2 combination.For example I have 3 medium t-shirts and 2 large t-shirts. medium T-shirt is set as default combination. whenever the customer adds the product to the cart .It only takes from the default combination.So it happens like if someone orders 3 large T-shirts, It adds 3 medium T-shirts to the  cart.

Kindly help me in this case.
I am using the version prestashop 1.5.5